# python lib for facebook instagram

Tags: python, facebook, instagram

I'm using a raspberry b+ to create some files that i would like to post on FB and Instagram (my account or any account). 
I have a good industrial computer bckground but not for the "cloud" stuff.

I seen the libs for python to connect to facebook and to instagram.
(facebook-sdk, python-instagram).
I understand the code of the examples etc...

I'm just missing the context of where should I put this code to be able to interact with these "social media" sites.

Could it work just with a UPLOADER.py ?
Or do I need to set up like a webserver ? Do i need the Json.simple/google and so on ?

I understand if it's a dumb question, but I'm a bit lost... 
Few "architectural" directions will do :). I'll get to understand the technical parts bymyself...

Thanks in advance! 
Cheers,
Mat

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set them up on "any" OS. Just make sure you have an internet connection. Also note, that those libraries wan't do anything unless you write the code. So you need to create a lightweight wrapper, that would pass credentials and triggers necessary functions, in a certain order. And that's pretty much it.

1. Could it work just with a UPLOADER.py ?
   Not sure what you referring to.
2. Or do I need to set up like a webserver ?

   No. You dont. It's not a requirements for the library.
3. Do i need the Json.simple/google

   Take a look at the file called `requirements.txt` it provides a set of libraries you need to have in addition to the standart/builtin libs.

Comment: Thanks ! For 1, i meant make just a simple python script to connect and upload a picture to facebook for example... is that what you're refering to by lightweight wrapper ? --- ok got it for 3! I'll install these libs!

Comment: That's right, that's exactly what I was trying to say